# Chef PEM file invalid or mis-named?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

My sytem username is `myuser` but I'm trying to bootstrap machines with a `chef-validator.pem` and then a `blah.pem` file, and getting the following error message:

```
ERROR: Failed to authenticate to https://mychef01 as blah with key
/etc/chef/blah.pem.
Response: Invalid signature for user or client 'blah'
```

Does this mean that the `blah.pem` file is invalid, or does it mean that it needs to match my system username (so, `myuser.pem`)? Either way, **what is the root problem and what is the fix?**

Comment: Where's that `blah.pem` coming from? Usually, the node registers itself as a client (using the validator key), when it does not find a client key.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKing (+1) - I am building an automated system that will bootstrap and configure nodes via Chef. I went to the chef server and created this `blah` user and downloaded its `blah.pem` file. I am now testing locally on my machine (where my username is `myuser`) and am wondering if my username has to match the name of the PEM file or if there is something wrong/invalid with the PEM file.

Comment: The pem file will be automatically generated. Just configure a node name (optionally, if not, chef will use the host name) and pass the validation key. No need to register the client manually.

Comment: And if you really wish to create it manually, the `client.rb` should have the `node_name` attribute set to the name you created, the client key could be named whatever you want with `client_key` attribute matching in `client.rb`, default is `/etc/chef/client.pem` on linux and `c:/chef/client.pem` on windows

Comment: Thanks everyone, in the end it turned out that my `blah` user didn't have admin permissions on the chef server. Setting to admin made the auth problems go away.

Comment: But you don't use that user for a normal node, don't you?

Comment: My software creates a new VM (using vSphere's SDK) and then uses JClouds-Chef to bootstrap and configure the VM; so yes, moving forward, `blah` is the chef user used by JClouds-Chef on the client-side.

Comment: You create a user in webui and not a client, a client can write its own node. That's the main difference. Users are for knife and clients are for nodes. And the user running chef should not have something to do (moreover you won't be able to create 2 VM with this method)

Comment: I agree. You want an admin user.

Answer (score 5):

From the Administration tab in chef name-validator.pem is generated from Organization level, while name.pem is generated from the User level. You may not have generated the user level pem yet.

Answer (score 3):

This is the issue with client key. I also faced this issue. I regenerated the key for user and added to {user}.pem file and it worked for me.

Comment: "I regenerated the key" -- you could really improve this answer by providing syntax here.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the same issue. In my case I was generating the key from the left sidebar and getting the same issue. But when I clicked in the user line "Gear"(action column), and then clicked in reset key to download it again (and place it poperly in the .chef directory), then it worked fine.

Other thing that may happened is that your .pem file is not correctly referenced in the knife.rb file

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the pem files copy from Chef Server to Workstation machine,

```
chef-server-ctl user-create USERNAME FIRSTNAME LASTNAME email-id@domain.com 'password' --filename ~/.chef/user-chef.pem

chef-server-ctl org-create ORG_NAME "orgname" --association_user USERNAME --filename ~/.chef/org-chef.pem
```

Once copied those *.pem files to the workstation, configure in ruby file config.rb

```
node_name                'node_name'
client_key               "user-chef.pem"
```

The value for node_name should be the USERNAME that was created on the Chef server.

Change user-chef.pem under client_key to reflect your .pem file for your user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error `Response: Invalid signature for user or client 'blah'` after kicking off a `kitchen test` but had a different solution.

I had made a mistake, my `Policyfile.rb` contained a `default_source` section that pointed at a different CHEF server org than was set to *currently active*.

```
default_source :chef_server, 'https://chef.awesome.com/organizations/bacon' do |s|
  s.preferred_for 'chef-client', 'cron', 'apt'
end
```

And my currently active knife profile required a **different** `pem` file than the org that contained my preferred source for some of the resources.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to select the **Users** tab from left sidebar and it will show you the your username over there.

Then you need to click on Gear icon from right section and click on `Reset Key`. It will generate a private key for you which you need to keep in your `.chef` directory with the name `<username>.pem`. Keep the same config in your `knife.rb` file too. For example

```
client_key               "#{current_dir}/<username>.pem"
```

Answer (score -2):

Go in https://api.chef.io/organizations

Administration tab. Go to Users menu. Generate a new key. Then go to Organitations menu item and generate a new knie and new key validator. Run it again.

Comment: I think regenerating the validation key is not the best advice for this question (the error message should differ). Be aware that regenerating the validation key invalidates the previous one.

Comment: Well. I got the same message error and what I wrote solve my problem.